# Upload Image in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery

I have an upload control and an Image Box. When I upload an image, I need to show it in the box. My image gets uploaded but is not displayed in the box.

The path of the uploaded image is returned as follows.

**~/Photos/Student/Student1.jpg**

How do I get the path as

**Photos/Student/Student1.jpg**

My client side function for upload is as follows.

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
                        url: 'FileUpload.ashx?id=' + FileFolder + '&Mainfolder=Photos' + '&parentfolder=Student',
                        secureuri: false,
                        fileElementId: 'uplPhoto',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data, status) {

                            if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                                if (data.error != '') {
                                    alert(data.error);
                                } else {

                                    $('#hdnFullPhotoPath').val(data.upfile);
                                    $('#uplPhoto').val("");
                                    $('#lblPhotoName').text('Photo uploaded successfully')

                                    $('#Image1').attr('src', data.upfile);
                                    alert(data.upfile);
                                }
                            }


                        },
                        error: function (data, status, e) {
                            alert(e);
                        }
                    });
                }

                else {
                    alert('The photo ' + filename + ' already exists');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('You can upload only jpg,jpeg,pdf,doc,docx,txt,zip,rar extensions files.');
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: @Aishvarya-Where do you want to get that path and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Coder, I need to show th uploaded image in the Image Box.

Comment: can you give your server side code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your FileUpload.ashx:

```
Dim fileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(("~/Photos/Student/" + fileName)))
```

And add an image control to your form and call it from codebehind as shown store the directory name in some session value and get it

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Photos/Student/" & Session("tempDir").ToString & "/" & filename
```

Answer (score 0):

All, thanks for your time and help.! The tilde(~) symbol was the issue - the file's path wasn't recognized. So I modified my code to replace it with empty space.

```
var orgpath = data.upfile;
var photopath = orgpath.replace('~/', '');
$('#<%= ImgFacultyPhoto.ClientID%>').attr('src', photopath);
```

Comment: Are you actually aware of what the `~` symbol is used for?  It's to denote the root of the current ASP.NET application, so you probably want to run `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(orgpath)` rather than remove the `~`.  Obviously that can only be done on the server side, as it's .NET code, not jQuery

Comment: @Freefaller, I do know that. I am handling it from the client since I don't want the page to be posted back.

Comment: Then tag your question as jQuery, not ASP.NET